# Django and compass with multiple apps

Tags: django, sass, compass-sass, django-compressor

I want to use [Compass](http://compass-style.org) to simplify the task of writing CSS in my Django app. But I don't know how to configure it.

I see django-compressor has support for SASS, but in order to use Compass I needed to dump the `_*.scss` files into my workspace (Django 1.4) since that's the working directory when django-compressor runs `scss` commands.

[Eric Meyer's approach](http://compass-style.org/blog/2011/05/09/compass-django/) sounds sensible (compile `.scss` files to `.css` during development and commit to SCM) but it's not obvious how I can use the SASS/Compass tools to compile `.scss` in multiple apps (both reusable and non-reusable) in a Django workspace.

I store static stylesheet files for each app in `<app>/static/<app>/css/`.

The issues I have are this:

1. `@import` doesn't work across apps
2. Putting `_*.scss` files in the workspace is unacceptable
3. Running `compass watch` in the workspace fails with:

   Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
4. Using `@include background(...)` fails:

   Syntax error: Undefined operation: "-compass-list-size(compact(#cccccc, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false)) gt 1"

Comment: Are _*.scss files partials? If so, why shouldn't they be included in the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

I've found it's much easier to essentially separate Django from Sass. You can still use them concurrently, but it might require another terminal window or so. In the end it's all about serving the compiled assets anyway.

I normally configure my project with a /src/ directory in the root, which is where I place my Sass files. I also set up a Compass project in that root directory with the compiled stylesheets going into /static/css/.

Obviously this can become problematic if you have a lot of applications within the project as you'd either want to create application directories within the root /static/ or create another Compass project in /

Normally, I use Grunt to compile my Sass/Compass files, so it's a bit more complicated, although easy to recreate.

Frank Wiles's post [Ultimate Front End Development Setup](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/oct/21/ultimate-front-end-development-setup/) is pretty close to how I setup my projects, although I skip using django-compressor as I feel adding middleware is unneeded, and obviously I use Grunt instead of Gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a tool like [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) (or even a bash script) to deal with the compilation and placement of files. As for the `compass watch` command, you might need to manually provide additional parameters for the location of the `.scss` and `.css` files in order for it to `watch` successfully (check the help docs by running `compass help watch`).